# Show other rows in MySQL table where a rows have a string with comma matched with a id

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, find-in-set

> I have a table called leads, and the other table is users. Now when the lead is consumed by the user, the field 'consumed_user_id' in leads adds the user_ids with comma delimiter in this field like (21,22,23,24). and other field is hide_seller_id, which adds the user id who want to hide the leads like this.

```
_______________________________________
| consumed_user_id  | hide_seller_id |
| 21,22,23,24       | NULL           |
|  NULL             | 21,22,23       |
_______________________________________
```

> Now both cant be filled, because row1 is consumed one by the user, its already hide, and row2 is hide by users but not consumed. so if user 21, want to see list, row1 and row2, both is not shown in his lead list.
>
> Now I want to show only those leads which are not consumed by the users and which has id in hide_seller_id row.
> I try this

```
SELECT * FROM leads 
WHERE status = 'verified' 
AND NOT FIND_IN_SET('$user_id',consumed_seller_id) OR consumed_seller_id 
IS NULL 
AND NOT FIND_IN_SET('$user_id',hide_seller_id) OR hide_seller_id IS NULL 
ORDER BY id DESC
```

> This is working for hide_seller_id but not working for consumed_seller_id, please help.

Comment: Probably `AND consumed_seller_id is null` - no user consumed it.

Comment: I write an example.the find_in_set works.you can update it to check if you sql work or not.https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=25e4e4a2922c09a77ace1a0f0ec6922b

Comment: In the end `consumed_user_id` is gonna be a pretty big string if you have a few hunderd users. My suggestion: drop that column and create a third table connecting `user_id` to consumed `lead_id`.  \

Comment: Please don't dump code in the comments. It's not readable. Edit your question if needed.

Comment: hi @Michel i update the question, please have a look guy, and please give me solution.

Comment: @Michel hello, i post the updated question can you have look, this is working for only one FIND_IN_SET